# Unable to enter unicode strings into MySQL using MySQLdb module in python

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I am using the `MySQLdb` python module to connect to a database. The method I am connecting to it is the following:

```
import MySQLdb as mysql

mysql_connection = mysql.connect(user=user, passwd=password, db=db, 
                                 charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
cursor           = mysql_connection.cursor()

# error checking snip here
# (ommitted for brevity)

return (mysql_connection, cursor)
```

Against this connection, I am executing queries that contain `utf-8` strings (`unicode` objects in python), like this:

```
[DEBUG] INSERT INTO Clients(clientid, login, pname, email) VALUES (304, 'sample_username', 'Φώτης Κ', 'example@example.com');
```

However I find that the data entered in the actual database are wrong, and are actually presented like this:

```
??????? ????????
```

I have actually confirmed that `mysql` is setup to accept unicode strings, as I have executed queries by hand that contain utf-8 characters and they are successful.

The result of the `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character_set%"` command is the following:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character_set%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and my schema for that particular table (at least for the relevant columns) is this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Clients`;
CREATE TABLE `Clients` (
    ...
    `login` VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `pname` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    ...
    );
```

Also, my terminal is setup to have `$LC_ALL` and `$LANG` setup to `el_GR.utf8`. What is possibly at fault here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh...

As with everything, I found the answer after I experimented a bit more myself. It seems that everything inserted is actually there, just that the `MySQL` Client didn't show it correctly.

As you could see from the character set results I posted in the question:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character_set%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`character_set_results` are set to `latin1`. Executing `SET character_set_results=utf8;` managed to fix everything and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the query below just after connecting, before any other that may contain utf8 characters:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

**UPDATE**

You should try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character_set%";` from your program to be sure that everything is set to utf8.

As you said just `SET NAMES` didn't work, [try being more verbose](http://tahpot.blogspot.com.br/2005/06/mysql-and-python-and-unicode.html):

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
SET character_set_connection=utf8;
```

Comment: I tried it in the past, and I have tried it again. It doesn't help. Besides, the existence of `charset='utf8', use_unicode=True` in the connection parameters are supposed to cause that `MySQL` instruction irrelevant.

Comment: Try outputing the content in hex, so we can see what's going on with the contents, using function `HEX(str)`... also, just to be sure, did you INSERT data using `SET NAMES` before? I mean, if you inserted other way/with other client, and now is SELECTing it, it may not work.